# Installing GLFW from source on Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, cmake, glfw

I am trying to install GLFW for use in Eclipse. I am using MinGW and am on Windows 7 64-bit. I tried to install GLFW using the pre-compiled binaries, but that did not work, as I could not build projects with it.

I installed CMake and follwed the instructions on http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html. I used CMake and it seemed to have worked, giving me a Makefile. Then I used mingw32-make to make it.

However, I am confused as to where the library files are, if there even are any. I was also under the impression that I needed a .dll file to use an external library. If anyone could help me through past this point that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you just download GLFW for c++, add the 'include' file directory to your 'include' file directories in ecliplse, then write
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> in your headers for your main class.

Comment: I was under the impression I had to link libraries somewhere? Is that something I have to do?

Comment: The libraries are linked through the header I believe. Here is additional information about this stuff straight of the GLFW website. http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html

Comment: @OrrenRavid should I have the glfw folder somewhere in particular, or have a certain link in my PATH variable?

Comment: I don't think you need to have the folder somewhere as long as you can have the link in your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was right. All I needed to do was to link the libraries, which can be found in {%PATH_TO_GLFW%}/src. The name of the library is glfw3.